# is whereBetween in laravel inclusive?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In my database there are 4 students:

1st Student's created_at = 2016-05-12 02:23:51

2nd Student's created_at = 2016-05-27 07:37:45

3rd Student's created_at = 2016-05-29 07:40:29

4th Student's created_at = 2016-05-29 07:50:05

Why does my code only returns the 1st student?

```
$students = Student::select('id as ID_NO', 'fname as Firstname', 'lname as Lastname', 'created_at')
                             ->whereBetween('created_at', 
                              [Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 12)->toDateString(),
                               Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 27)->toDateString()])
```

The 1st and 2nd student should be returned. Is the "to" part inclusive in whereBetween or there's something wrong with my code ?

I need your help guys. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because when you stated `Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 27)->toDateString()` it means student that created before 2016-05-27 00:00:00, since your second student created after that time so he's excluded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to format your `created_at` to `Y-m-d` format.
Please see the change:

```
$students = Student::select('id as ID_NO', 'fname as Firstname', 'lname as Lastname', 'created_at')
                                 ->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), 
                                  [Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 12)->toDateString(),
                                   Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 27)->toDateString()])
```

Comment: Your answer produces an error: Unknown column 'date(created_at)'

Comment: @arthlimchiu I have added `DB::raw()` to `where` clause

Answer (score 108):

For others who end up here and want the answer to the question asked (in case it's updated… "Is whereBetween in Laravel inclusive?"):

**Yes.**

Comment: The answer is No

Comment: It is inclusive. Just make sure to mention the time with the date.

Comment: ty. this should be in the laravel docs. not sure why is not

Answer (score 10):

Laravel search `between`, this means it will get all the rows between `2016-05-12 00:00:00` and `2016-05-27 00:00:00`. Your second user is created at `2016-05-27 07:37:45`, this is outside the range so Laravel won't fetch it.

Use this and try if this works:

```php
$students = Student::select('id as ID_NO', 'fname as Firstname', 'lname as Lastname', 'created_at')
    ->whereBetween('created_at' [
        Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 12)->toDateString(),
        Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 28)->toDateString()
    ])
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Your explanation clears it. Is there any other way aside a +1 for 'to' ?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers here have indicated, yes it is inclusive, but you have to require the time in your parameters in order to make it inclusive - in human terms. My example below sets the time (using Carbon's `setTime` method) to allow the widest range of chronologic inclusivity.

```
->whereBetween('start_point_utc', [
          \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $startDate)->setTimezone('UTC')->setTime(0, 0, 0)->toDateTimeString(),
          \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $endDate)->setTimezone('UTC')->setTime(24, 59, 59)->toDateTimeString()
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution

```
$students = Student::select('id as ID_NO', 'fname as Firstname', 'lname as Lastname', 'created_at')
                             ->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), 
                              [Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 12)->toDateString(),
                               Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 5, 27)->toDateString()])
```