# order by not working with mysql date function laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a query where I've to show the records on ascending order base and in database my table field `created_at` has `2016-11-29 12:18:22` and I want to retrieve date only so I made `laravel` query and my `laravel` query is

```
$countOffer = countOffer::select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS created_at"))->where("offerStatus", "!=", 7)->orderBy("created_at", "ASC")->get()->toArray();
```

now the problem is when I add `order by` clause at `created_at` field it shows `0000-00-00` so I made query on `MySQL yog` for testing purpose and query is

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS created_at FROM countOffer WHERE offerStatus != 7 ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

it is also showing the same value `0000-00-00` and search it on different forums but didn't get any solution related to my problem.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: put one more condition : `created_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Comment: same query I've made on `MySQLyog` but it is also not working.

Comment: Can you check again by removing `DATE(created_at)`

Comment: but I don't have any `0000-00-00 00:00:00` like this in my table except two records it is showing `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for all records.

Comment: `SELECT created_at FROM countOffer WHERE offerStatus != 7` query is working and showing `2016-11-29 12:18:22` I need only date not time that's why I use `DATE` function.

Comment: and same thing is not working in `laravel` because of `DATE` function and `order by`.

Comment: try `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%y-%m-%d') AS created FROM countOffer WHERE offerStatus != 7 ORDER BY created ASC`

Comment: Why would it matter whether you order by the date only, or the full date-time combination in the first place?

Comment: `Mr. Shaunak Shukla` your suggest for one more condition work for me. Thanks

Comment: @ShaunakShukla can I do like this `$countOffer->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS created_at"), array($startDate, $endDate));` because almost same thing is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584505/is-wherebetween-in-laravel-inclusive#answer-37584689.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your query like below step

**Step 1 :**

```
$countOffer = countOffer::select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS created_at"))
->where("offerStatus", "!=", 7)->orderBy("created_at", "ASC")->get();
```

**Step 2 :**

Then you should get the `$countOffer` array of what you need.

Hope this helps you

Comment: What if I do `$countOffer = $countOffer->select(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS created_at"))
->where("offerStatus", "!=", 7)->orderBy("created_at", "ASC")->get();` result will be same and return array.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion to remove `toArray()` worked.

Comment: One more thing can I do like this `$countOffer->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) AS created_at"), array($startDate, $endDate));` but its not working.

Comment: AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd same thing is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584505/is-wherebetween-in-laravel-inclusive#answer-37584689.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `created_at` only field by using `get(['created_at'])`:

```
$countOffers = countOffer:where('offerStatus', '!=', 7)->oldest()->get(['created_at']);
```

In this case, you're using Eloquent without raw queries and it's so much better to use it to keep your app maintainable.

Also, since `created_at` is a Carbon instance, you can do this in a controller, view or any other place of your app:

```
@foreach ($countOffers as $countOffer)
    {{ countOffer->created_at->toDateString() }}
@endforeach
```

If you need the data for exporting, use the `map()` collection method to convert Carbon instance to whatever format you want.